# how to avoid repeated authorizations from linkedin to same application

Tags: java, oauth, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

```
final LinkedInOAuthService oauthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(consumerKeyValue, consumerSecretValue);
LinkedInRequestToken requestToken = oauthService.getOAuthRequestToken(callbackUrl);
session.setAttribute("requestToken", requestToken);
String authUrl = requestToken.getAuthorizationUrl(); 
return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + authUrl);
```

I am using the above code block to make user grant permission to my application from LinkedIN.
The authorization screen is appearing everytime when I redirect user to **authURL**  with the same default scope.
Not able to figure out if I am missing anything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your OAuth endpoint from https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize to https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authenticate. This should work for you.